# MappedBy reference an unknown target entity property twice?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query, I happen to have a table called "SGOrdCompra" that linked him with a "SGPersona" twice, table like this:

**Sgordcompra.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`SGOrdCompra`", schema = "`public`")
public class Sgordcompra implements java.io.Serializable {

    .....
    private Sgpersona sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante;
    private Sgpersona sgpersonaByIcodComprador;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "`iCodSolicitante`", nullable = false)
    public Sgpersona getSgpersonaByIcodSolicitante() {
        return this.sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante;
    }

    public void setSgpersonaByIcodSolicitante(
            Sgpersona sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante) {
        this.sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante = sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "`iCodComprador`", nullable = false)
    public Sgpersona getSgpersonaByIcodComprador() {
        return this.sgpersonaByIcodComprador;
    }

    public void setSgpersonaByIcodComprador(Sgpersona sgpersonaByIcodComprador) {
        this.sgpersonaByIcodComprador = sgpersonaByIcodComprador;
    }

}
```

**Sgpersona.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`SGPersona`", schema = "`public`")
public class Sgpersona implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int icodPersona;
    private Set<Sgrencajchica> sgrencajchicas = new HashSet<Sgrencajchica>(0);
    ....
    private Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodComprador = new HashSet<Sgordcompra>(0);    
    private Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante = new HashSet<Sgordcompra>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sgpersona")
    public Set<Sgrencajchica> getSgrencajchicas() {
        return this.sgrencajchicas;
    }

    public void setSgrencajchicas(Set<Sgrencajchica> sgrencajchicas) {
        this.sgrencajchicas = sgrencajchicas;
    }

    .......

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sgpersona")
    public Set<Sgordcompra> getSgordcomprasForIcodComprador() {
        return this.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador;
    }

    public void setSgordcomprasForIcodComprador(
            Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodComprador) {
        this.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador = sgordcomprasForIcodComprador;
    }



    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sgpersona")
    public Set<Sgordcompra> getSgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante() {
        return this.sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante;
    }

    public void setSgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante(
            Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante) {
        this.sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante = sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante;
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iGenericDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.sgkyros.common.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: org.sgkyros.common.entity.Sgordcompra.sgpersona in org.sgkyros.common.entity.Sgpersona.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador
```

But testing it if I comment the lines of code that relate to the "Sgpersona" class, works for me normally, should it be ....?

```
private Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodComprador = new HashSet<Sgordcompra>(0);    
private Set<Sgordcompra> sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante = new HashSet<Sgordcompra>(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The mappedBy property is trying to reference an invalid property "sgpersona" in the class "Sgordcompra". The OneToMany mapping should be done as follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sgpersonaByIcodComprador")
public Set<Sgordcompra> getSgordcomprasForIcodComprador() {
    return this.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sgpersonaByIcodSolicitante")
public Set<Sgordcompra> getSgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante() {
    return this.sgordcomprasForIcodSolicitante;
}
```

Comment: Friend does not work that way, I still generates the same error.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: org.sgkyros.common.entity.Sgordcompra.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador  in org.sgkyros.common.entity.Sgpersona.sgordcomprasForIcodComprador

Comment: Can you post the complete exception trace

Comment: @Hernando There was a typo in the answer I had posted. It should have been "sgpersonaByIcodComprador" instead of "sgordcomprasForIcodComprador".Sorry for the mistake. I have updated the answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in **Sgrencajchica** class. You need to have an attribute named "sgpersona" in it. Post the code for your **Sgrencajchica** class.